# How to share programmatically a message with a hyperlink from my Android app to Telegram without using bots?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, hyperlink, telegram

I want to get something like this:

*Download my app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.id.app.packagename)*

...but in a Telegram message when the user clicks a button in my Android app. Note the link in the word ***here***.

I have the following code inside the button's onClickListener callback:

```
String msg = "Download my app <a href=\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.id.app.packagename\">here</a>";
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
myIntent.setType("text/plain");
myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with"));
```

However, the above code does not create a clikable link on the word ***here***, instead it explicitly shows what I have in the **msg** variable.

I tried with **HTML**:

```
<a href="https://example.com">This is an example</a>
```

...and with **markdown**:

```
[This is an example](https://example.com)
```

Both cases don't work for my.

How to share programmatically a message with a hyperlink from my Android app to Telegram without using bots?

Please, note in my question that **I don't want to use Telegram bots**, like:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage?text=%3Ca+href%3D%27url.com%27%3Eword%3C%2Fa%3E&chat_id=<chat_id>&parse_mode=HTML
```