I can't share hyperlink on Android
I simply copied the following code to my Android app:
String textToShare = "Visit <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> for more info.";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sample");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(textToShare));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));

but in GMail I get the text "Visit google for more info." without a hyperlink.
What can cause this?
My device is Samsung Galaxy A54, Android 14.
EDIT1
I get a plain text, but not HTML. For example if I try
String textToShare = "Visit <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> for more info. <b>Bold text</b>.";

with Telegram, I get this:

and GMail also does not display "Bold text" as bold.

Probably related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66071840/how-to-share-programmatically-a-message-with-a-hyperlink-from-my-android-app-to How to share programmatically a message with a hyperlink from my Android app to Telegram without using bots?

This is all up to the app you're sharing it with, how to interpret and display the data.  There's no way to force it to do a certain thing.

HTML is for browsers
